# how set flutter LocalNotification.schedule alarm every 2weeks?

Tags: flutter, schedule, localnotification, flutter-notification

example during 3 weeks.

1 week Monday - alarm on
2 weeks Monday - alarm no
3 weeks Monday - alarm on

how can I do it?
I try DateTimeComponents.dateAndTime, but it's only run for one day.
and I try DateTimeComponents.dayOfMonthAndTime, but it's only run the first monday in a month.
and I try DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime, but it's run every week

I wonder how to set duration 2weeks.

```
wait for flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
            int.parse(_alarmID), // id는 unique해야합니다. int값
            notiTitle,
            notiDesc,
            _setNotiTime(),
            detail,
            androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
            uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
                UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
            matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime,
          );
```

Comment: So you want to set alarm every week of monday? Your question is confusing.

Comment: oh, sorry no. i want alarm monday per 2weeks.

Comment: example) 
2023/1/1~1/7 - first week - monday alarm on
2023/1/8~1/14 - second week - monday alarm none
2023/1/15~1/21 - third week - monday alarm on
2023/1/22~1/28 - forth week - monday alarm none

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.